# Clearing form input after submitting using setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, setstate, rerender

**UPDATE** : There is a problem in the FormInput component, the state is changing but the new state passed as props to FormInput is not being reflected.

I was creating this contact form in react and I wanted it to clear after submission.
After rigorous searching on the web, I couldn't find why my this.setState is not clearing the input fields as I'm changing all the inputs to an empty string. Take a look:

```
class contactPage extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        name :'',
        email : '',
        subject : '',
        message : ''
    }
}
handleChange = (e) =>{
const {name,value} = e.target;
this.setState({
    [name] : value
})

}
handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
        name :'',
        email : '',
        subject : '',
        message : ''
    });
} 
render(){
    const { name,email,subject,message } = this.state;
    return(
    <div className='contact-page'>
        <h1 className='title'> Contact Page </h1>
        <div className='form-container'>
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <div className='input-container'>
                    <div className='form-input'>
                        <FormInput handleChange = {this.handleChange} value={name} type='text' name ='name' label='Full Name'/>
                    </div>
                    <div className='form-input'>
                        <FormInput handleChange = {this.handleChange} value={email} type='email' name ='email' label='Email'/>
                    </div>
                    <div className='form-input'>
                        <FormInput handleChange = {this.handleChange} value={subject} type='text' name ='subject' label='Subject'/>
                    </div>
                    <div className='form-input'>
                        <FormInput handleChange = {this.handleChange} value={message} name ='text-area' label='Message'/>
                    </div>
                    <div className='form-input'>
                        <CustomButton
                         type='submit' value='SEND' >SEND</CustomButton>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>)
}
```

}

[image]

Comment: e.target.reset() does the job but I wanted to know why this does not work

Comment: Is handleSubmit being called? Could you kindly check that?

Comment: yes it is called I had a console.log() in my handle submit, I have checked

Comment: What is `FormInput`? Is it a controlled input? If it's not a controlled input, then this is the reason.

Comment: FormInput is a component template i made so that I can further reuse it in my application, it is basically a input tag with a bunch of css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not very confidant that the state isn't chaging, it might be a problem with your inputs

I've done just the same component, using native inputs instead, and it works perfectly